# regex for the symbols (!@#$%^&*_) before the first characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a filename say  _ab_c.txt & I want to remove the first underscore before a , so that I should have a file name like ab_c.txt .
I am using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
'_ab_c.txt'.replace(/^_/, '')
```

will do. Or if you want to replace other characters as listed in the title,

```
'_ab_c.txt'.replace(/^[!@#$%^&*_]+/, '')
```

will get rid of any number of them.